# How to display a border-bottom only if table cells are not empty (CSS)

Tags: css

I've got a Filemaker calculation that generates an HTML page with several tables.

If the calculation results in values for certain fields the result would be

```
<table>
<tr><td>Example value 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Example value 2</td></tr>
...
</table>
```

If the calculation finds no values to be displayed, the result would simply be

```
<table>
</table>
```

In the first case, I want to the table to display a border at the bottom (or any other horizontal line);
in the second case, I don't want to display a border at the bottom.

I cannot find a way to get this done using a **CSS**...

Thanks in adavance  :-)

Comment: You should avoid making empty table. `<table></table>` is incorrect syntax, it should contain at least one `tr` with at least one `td`.

Comment: I have to agree, the place to fix this is in your generator, any CSS only  solution won't be cross-browser anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get as close as possible with this, given you can't change the markup:

```
table tr:last td { border-bottom: solid 1px blue; }
```

If you're generating multiple tables you need this ([though less-supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)):

```
table tr:last-child td { border-bottom: solid 1px blue; }
```

No guarantees on IE6 though.

However, I **strongly** suggest you don't generate an empty table if you can avoid it, it's invalid HTML.  If you did this your CSS gets simpler as well, just giving table this:

```
table { border-bottom: solid 1px blue; }
```

Comment: Isn't it `:last-child`? I never knew about the shorthand, thanks if it works! +1

Comment: @alex - Yes if you're generating more than 1 table per you'd switch to that, but it's even less-supported, so hopefully it's 1 table...I'll update

Comment: Guys, Thank you very much for your fast help and comments...

@Nick Craver - Thanks for this solution. It works well!

Here's the reason for my request: When a user opens a record in my  FileMaker solution, the corresponding HTML code is being generated and displayed (in this case the result of the calculation cannot be stored in FileMaker). I would have preferred to let the generator do less calculation work if simple CSS / HTML formatting would have solved the problem. But I'll stick to your advice of not creating empty tables - to avoid trouble in the future...  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Easy using javascript, but if it has to be css only, what about using the  tag to place your border on?

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Example value 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Example value 2</td></tr>
    ...
    <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

Example here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tbody